# Map data from one dictionary into another

Tags: json, dictionary, julia

I have data from two APIs in JSON format and parsing them into 2 dictionaries (d1, d2).

I need to derive two additional fields FieldName(from d1), attrVal (from d2) by mapping subAttrDefId present in d2 ("attrValues") with subAttribDefId present in d2.

I have tried below code, but it's giving me "BoundsError"

```
resp = HTTP.get(URL1)
resp2 = HTTP.get(URL2)
global dict1, dict2

jsonStr = String(resp.body)
dict1 = JSON.parse(jsonStr)

jsonStr2 = String(resp2.body)
dict2 = JSON.parse(jsonStr2)

field_names = values(dict1)

    for item in dict2
        # for field_name in field_names
        #     item[field_name] = missing
        # end
        attr_vals = item["attrValues"]
        for attr_val in attr_vals
            field_name = dict1[attr_val["subAttrDefId"]]
            item[field_name] = attr_val["attr_val"]
            delete!(item,"attrValues")
        end
    end
```

Sample data from 1st API(d1):

```
[
   {
      "DefId":4327,
      "DefVersionId":4326,
      "attrValues":[
         {
            "subAttrValId":4328,
            "DefId":4327,
            "subAttrDefId":3888,
            "attrVal":"276",
            "crtUserid":"3456789",
            "crtTmstmp":null,
            "updtUserid":null,
            "updtTmstmp":"2023-01-10T14:08:36.000+00:00"
         },
         {
            "subAttrValId":4329,
            "DefId":4327,
            "subAttrDefId":3889,
            "attrVal":"52",
            "crtUserid":"3456789",
            "crtTmstmp":null,
            "updtUserid":null,
            "updtTmstmp":"2023-01-10T14:08:36.000+00:00"
         },
         {
            "subAttrValId":4330,
            "DefId":4327,
            "subAttrDefId":3890,
            "attrVal":"50",
            "crtUserid":"3456789",
            "crtTmstmp":null,
            "updtUserid":null,
            "updtTmstmp":"2023-01-10T14:08:36.000+00:00"
         },
         {
            "subAttrValId":4331,
            "DefId":4327,
            "subAttrDefId":3891,
            "attrVal":"24",
            "crtUserid":"3456789",
            "crtTmstmp":null,
            "updtUserid":null,
            "updtTmstmp":"2023-01-10T14:08:36.000+00:00"
         }
],
      "code":"AB",
      "typeCode":"00",
      "crtUserid":"12345",
      "crtTmstmp":null,
      "updtUserid":"23456",
      "updtTmstmp":"2023-01-10T14:08:36.000+00:00"
   }
]
```

Sample data from 2nd API(d2):

```
[
   {
      "subAttribDefId":3886,
      "displayLabel":"string",
      "attribDesc":"string",
      "attribName":"string",
      "attribDataType":"string",
      "attrFormat":"string",
      "crtUserid":"string",
      "crtTmstmp":"2022-12-21T19:07:14.000+00:00",
      "updtUserid":"string",
      "updtTmstmp":"2022-12-21T19:07:14.000+00:00",
      "FieldName":null,
      "category":null,
      "subcategory":null
   },
   {
      "subAttribDefId":3887,
      "displayLabel":"string",
      "attribDesc":"string",
      "attribName":"string",
      "attribDataType":"string",
      "attrFormat":"string",
      "crtUserid":"string",
      "crtTmstmp":"2022-12-21T19:08:18.000+00:00",
      "updtUserid":"string",
      "updtTmstmp":"2022-12-21T19:08:18.000+00:00",
      "FieldName":null,
      "category":null,
      "subcategory":null
   },
   {
      "subAttribDefId":3888,
      "displayLabel":"Number of bucket",
      "attribDesc":"Number of bucket",
      "attribName":"numbuckets",
      "attribDataType":"number",
      "attrFormat":"",
      "crtUserid":"12345",
      "crtTmstmp":"2022-12-21T19:08:56.000+00:00",
      "updtUserid":null,
      "updtTmstmp":"2022-12-21T19:08:56.000+00:00",
      "FieldName":null,
      "category":null,
      "subcategory":null
   },
   {
      "subAttribDefId":3889,
      "displayLabel":"Cabin",
      "attribDesc":"class Cabin",
      "attribName":"aCabin",
      "attribDataType":"number",
      "attrFormat":"",
      "crtUserid":"1234",
      "crtTmstmp":"2022-12-21T19:08:56.000+00:00",
      "updtUserid":null,
      "updtTmstmp":"2022-12-21T19:08:56.000+00:00",
      "FieldName":null,
      "category":null,
      "subcategory":null
   }
```

```
**Dict1**:

Any[Dict{String, Any}("crtTmstmp" => "2023-01-12T08:17:49.000+00:00", "attribName" => "buckets", "subAttribDefId" => 1, "attrFormat" => "^[\\d]*\$", "updtTmstmp" => "2023-01-12T08:17:49.000+00:00", "displayLabel" => "buckets", "crtUserid" => "23456", "FieldName" => nothing, "attribDesc" => "buckets", "category" => "Seat Attributes", 
"updtUserid" => nothing, "attribDataType" => "number", "subcategory" => nothing), Dict{String, Any}("crtTmstmp" => "2023-01-12T08:17:49.000+00:00", "attribName" => "fCabin", "subAttribDefId" => 2, "attrFormat" => "^[\\d]*\$", "updtTmstmp" => "2023-01-12T08:17:49.000+00:00", "displayLabel" => "F Cabin", "crtUserid" => "23456", "FieldName" => nothing, "attribDesc" => "First class Cabin", "category" => "Seat Attributes", "updtUserid" => nothing, "attribDataType" => "number", "subcategory" => nothing), Dict{String, Any}("crtTmstmp" => "2023-01-12T08:17:49.000+00:00", "attribName" => "jCabin", "subAttribDefId" => 3, "attrFormat" => "^[\\d]*\$", "updtTmstmp" => "2023-01-12T08:17:49.000+00:00", "displayLabel" => "J Cabin", "crtUserid" => "23456", "FieldName" => nothing, "attribDesc" => "J Cabin", "category" => "Seat Attributes", "updtUserid" => nothing, "attribDataType" => "number", "subcategory" => nothing), Dict{String, Any}("crtTmstmp" => "2023-01-12T08:17:49.000+00:00", "attribName" => "oCabin", "subAttribDefId" => 4, "attrFormat" => "^[\\d]*\$", "updtTmstmp" => "2023-01-12T08:17:49.000+00:00", "displayLabel" => "O Cabin", "crtUserid" => "23456", "FieldName" => nothing, "attribDesc" => "O Cabin", "category" => "Seat Attributes", "updtUserid" => nothing, "attribDataType" => "number", "subcategory" => nothing), Dict{String, Any}("crtTmstmp" => "2023-01-12T08:17:49.000+00:00", "attribName" => "yPlusCabin", "subAttribDefId" 
=> 5, "attrFormat" => "^[\\d]*\$", "updtTmstmp" => "2023-01-12T08:17:49.000+00:00", "displayLabel" => "Y+ Cabin", "crtUserid" => "23456", "FieldName" => nothing, "attribDesc" => "Y Plus Cabin", "category" => "Seat Attributes", "updtUserid" => nothing, "attribDataType" => "number", "subcategory" => nothing)]

**Dict2:**
Any[Dict{String, Any}("proxyCode" => "000", "crtTmstmp" => nothing, "equipCode" => "ABC", "proxyequipCode" => "ABC", "reportequipcode" => "ABC", "userTypeCode" => "ABC", "code" => "AB", "isUserDefined" => 0, "updtTmstmp" => "2023-01-10T14:08:36.000+00:00", "ftype" => "000", "crtUserid" => "123456", "attrValues" => Any[Dict{String, Any}("crtTmstmp" => nothing, "updtUserid" => nothing, "updtTmstmp" => "2023-01-10T14:08:36.000+00:00", "attrVal" => "276", "subAttribValId" => 4328, "crtUserid" => "123456", "subAttribDefId" => 3888, "subDefId" => 4327), Dict{String, Any}("crtTmstmp" => nothing, "updtUserid" => nothing, "updtTmstmp" => "2023-01-10T14:08:36.000+00:00", "attrVal" => "52", "subAttribValId" => 4329, "crtUserid" => "123456", "subAttribDefId" => 3889, "subDefId" => 4327), Dict{String, Any}("crtTmstmp" => nothing, "updtUserid" => nothing, "updtTmstmp" => "2023-01-10T14:08:36.000+00:00", "attrVal" => "50", "subAttribValId" => 4330, "crtUserid" => "123456", "subAttribDefId" => 3890, "subDefId" => 4327), Dict{String, Any}("crtTmstmp" => nothing, "updtUserid" => nothing, "updtTmstmp" => "2023-01-10T14:08:36.000+00:00", "attrVal" => "24", "subAttribValId" => 4331, "crtUserid" => "123456", "subAttribDefId" => 3891, "subDefId" => 4327), Dict{String, Any}("crtTmstmp" => nothing, "updtUserid" => nothing, "updtTmstmp" => "2023-01-10T14:08:36.000+00:00", "attrVal" => "46", "subAttribValId" => 4332, "crtUserid" => "123456", "subAttribDefId" => 3892, "subFletDefId" => 4327), Dict{String, Any}("crtTmstmp" => nothing, "updtUserid" => nothing, "updtTmstmp" => "2023-01-10T14:08:36.000+00:00", "attrVal" => "202", "subAttribValId" => 4333, "crtUserid" => "123456", "subAttribDefId" => 3893, "subDefId" => 4327), Dict{String, Any}("crtTmstmp" => nothing, "updtUserid" => nothing, "updtTmstmp" => "2023-01-10T14:08:36.000+00:00", "attrVal" => "2", "subAttribValId" => 4334, "crtUserid" => "123456", "subAttribDefId" => 3894, "subDefId" => 4327), Dict{String, Any}("crtTmstmp" => nothing, "updtUserid" => nothing, "updtTmstmp" => "2023-01-10T14:08:36.000+00:00", "attrVal" => "Normal", "subAttribValId" => 4335, "crtUserid" => "123456", "subAttribDefId" => 3895, "subDefId" => 4327), Dict{String, Any}("crtTmstmp" => nothing, "updtUserid" => nothing, "updtTmstmp" => "2023-01-10T14:08:36.000+00:00", "attrVal" => "8", "subAttribValId" => 4336, "crtUserid" => "123456", "subAttribDefId" => 3896, "subDefId" => 4327), Dict{String, Any}("crtTmstmp" => nothing, "updtUserid" => nothing, "updtTmstmp" => "2023-01-10T14:08:36.000+00:00", "attrVal" => "180", "subAttribValId" => 4337, "crtUserid" => "123456", "subAttribDefId" => 3897, "subDefId" => 4327), Dict{String, Any}("crtTmstmp" => nothing, "updtUserid" => nothing, "updtTmstmp" => "2023-01-10T14:08:36.000+00:00", "attrVal" => "218", "subAttribValId" => 4338, "crtUserid" => "123456", "subAttribDefId" => 3898, "subDefId" => 4327), Dict{String, Any}("crtTmstmp" => nothing, "updtUserid" => nothing, "updtTmstmp" => "2023-01-10T14:08:36.000+00:00", "attrVal" => "9", "subAttribValId" => 4339, "crtUserid" => "123456", "subAttribDefId" => 3899, "subDefId" => 4327), Dict{String, Any}("crtTmstmp" => nothing, "updtUserid" => nothing, "updtTmstmp" => "2023-01-10T14:08:36.000+00:00", "attrVal" => "181", "subAttribValId" => 4340, "crtUserid" => "123456", "subAttribDefId" => 3900, "subDefId" => 4327), Dict{String, Any}("crtTmstmp" => nothing, "updtUserid" => nothing, "updtTmstmp" => "2023-01-10T14:08:36.000+00:00", "attrVal" => "-", "subAttribValId" => 4341, "crtUserid" => "123456", "subAttribDefId" => 3901, "subDefId" => 4327), Dict{String, Any}("crtTmstmp" => nothing, "updtUserid" => nothing, "updtTmstmp" => "2023-01-10T14:08:36.000+00:00", "attrVal" => "40000", "subAttribValId" => 4342, "crtUserid" => "123456", "subAttribDefId" => 3902, "subDefId" => 4327), Dict{String, Any}("crtTmstmp" => nothing, "updtUserid" => nothing, "updtTmstmp" => "2023-01-10T14:08:36.000+00:00", "attrVal" => "2.71", "subAttribValId" => 4343, "crtUserid" => "123456", "subAttribDefId" => 3903, "subDefId" => 4327), Dict{String, Any}("crtTmstmp" => nothing, "updtUserid" => nothing, "updtTmstmp" => "2023-01-10T14:08:36.000+00:00", "attrVal" => "2.96", "subAttribValId" => 4344, "crtUserid" => "123456", "subAttribDefId" => 3904, "subDefId" => 4327), Dict{String, Any}("crtTmstmp" => nothing, "updtUserid" => nothing, "updtTmstmp" => "2023-01-10T14:08:36.000+00:00", "attrVal" => "2%", "subAttribValId" => 4345, "crtUserid" => "123456", "subAttribDefId" => 3905, "subDefId" => 4327), Dict{String, Any}("crtTmstmp" => nothing, "updtUserid" => nothing, "updtTmstmp" => "2023-01-10T14:08:36.000+00:00", "attrVal" => "-3%", "subAttribValId" => 4346, "crtUserid" => "123456", "subAttribDefId" => 3906, "subDefId" => 4327)], "bodyType" => "W", "DefVersionId" => 4326, "subDefId" => 4327, "updtUserid" => "456789")]
```

Comment: The top level JSON here is a Vector. Could you also post the JSON conversions you are getting from the JSON module you used? This would help know what d1 and d2, dict1 and dict2 are.

Comment: @Bill Thanks for replying, Added JSON conversions above. please let me know if you need anything else

Comment: Are you trying to extract fields only if the subAttribDefId is present in the dict and matches in value with the other Dict? Do the Dicts need to be at the same nesting level in the JSON structure, or can they be at different nesting levels?